# Prevent Null value on NestJs dto properties

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I want to prevent null value on nestjs dto **optional** properties.

```
@ApiProperty({
  type: String,
  format: 'string',
})
@IsOptional()
@IsString()
readonly name?: string;
```

A possible workaround is this:

```
@ApiProperty({
  type: String,
  format: 'string',
  required: false, // This will make it optional for the docs
})
@ValidateIf((o) => o.name !== undefined) 
@IsString()
readonly name?: string;
```

I'm expecting something like: `@IsNotNull`

Comment: I would expect that `IsOptional` and `IsString` already cover the fact that the value can't be `null`. Have you checked that you *can* pass `null` as the value of `address`?

Comment: Unfortunately `IsOptional` will skip validation for `undefined` and `null` value ... so the `IsString` is skipped.

Comment: Have you tried `@IsDefined` or `@IsNotEmpty`? From reading the docs it seems like one them should get you the desired result.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I need to keep the `@IsOptional` decorator. Otherwise the `@IsString` would have been enough in this case. Thanks for the answers anyway.

Comment: Why do you want to keep `@IsOptional `? There are plenty of solutions without using it

Comment: Fair point @Fcmam5, I like the usage of self-explanatory decorator. I know there are some workaround but they reduce code readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you have a fair and valid point that you want to have a clean self-explanatory decorator. But unfortunately, the behavior of [class-validator's `@IsOptional`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators) makes it impossible to be used with other decorators to not allow `null` like `@NotEquals(null)`...

> `@IsOptional()`   Checks if given value is empty (=== null, === undefined)
> and if so, **ignores all the validators on the property**.

And I didn't find any initiative **YET** from the library's maintainers to add a cleaner approach to achieve it, check these open issues:

- https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/686
- https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/491
- https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/637

Now it's up to you, you can implement your own decorator and import it to your DTO class, or use a library that does that for you like [class-validator-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator-extended), it seems that they offer an [`@Optional`](https://pigulla.github.io/class-validator-extended/functions/Optional.html) decorator (note that they suggest that you import from `class-validator-extended/dist/minimal` if you don't have dayjs).

If you don't want to have the full npm package installed just to use that one decorator, I believe that you can just get inspired by this portion from [class-validator-extended/optional.decorator.ts#L21](https://github.com/pigulla/class-validator-extended/blob/main/src/common/optional/optional.decorator.ts#L21)

Answer (score 1):

*If I'm going to use both optional and ensure that the key value is not null, using 'transform' seems appropriate here. It doesn't skip this check, so it prevents errors in checks like 'isEnum' in case of returning false.*

Example:

```
 @IsOptional()
  @IsEnum(UserType)
  @Transform(({ value }) => {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  })
  type?: UserType;
```